# 3kW power supply from 230Vac input

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, high-voltage, high-current

What kind of power supply topology(s) should you use for a CC and CV programmable power supply with the following parameters?

- input: **230V**ac
- output: **0 - 1000V**dc / **3A max.**

Comment: LLC half-bridge, possibly interleaved.

Comment: Either full bridge or half bridge or LLC half bridge can be acceptable. I don't think interleaved converters is necessary here, because output current is quite low *(If I'm wrong, please someone correct me)*. For programmable output, you'll need another (auxillary) converter for supplying controller IC. Note that if you go for opamps at the output section (i.e. for CC and CV) be careful for the stability.

Comment: Are you trying to build a 3kW 1kV PSU? Because odds are you shouldn't.

Comment: There may be good reason for such a PSU but they will be rare.  This will be a rather big unit and purchasing a used unit will be cheaper than sourcing the parts if you just need one or two. Prices for new on AliExpress and such are over US$3000 and the size is half a washing machine.

Comment: Yes - I shouldn't! We use such a power supply at work. Since my knowledge does not cover high-power supplies, I won't even think of building one with those voltage levels. But I really want to understand the typology you might use, and how this thing - especially the CC and CV - works at this power levels.